# Concept for changing Console Application in Qt Gui Application

Tags: c++, qt

having implemented a c++ class "quiz" that exchanges information with the player via console in/output, I want to replace the console by a Gui.
Therefore I implemented an appropriate class "`MainWindow`" (with `QCheckboxes`, `QButtonGroup`,...) as subclass of `QWindow`.

Now, I doubt about the relation of these two classes:

In my opinion, "quiz" HAS A "`MainWindow`"  (like its element of type "`quiz_content`"). In consequence I enlarged "quiz" by a pointer to a `QApplication` and a pointer to "`MainWindow`". The constructor of "quiz" creates the corresponding elements on the heap and starts the `exec()` routine. However, a signal (like `buttonClicked()`) would have to call a method belonging to "quiz" (which does not have slots as pure c++).

Next try: "`MainWindow`" HAS A "`quiz`". So I can start the `QApplication` within main as shown by all beginners' examples. I can't give strong arguments why I don't like this relationship. In fact, it seems to lead to bigger modification of `quiz.play()`, a method, that manages the game.

Question: what is the usual way to combine traditional code with Qt application? Are there multiple possibilities? Which is the most efficient one regarding re-implementation of "`quiz`"?

Thanks for answering to my greenhorn question!

Further explanation: Thank you for responding so quickly! Sorry, that my question has not been formulated clearly.
As you mentioned I attached some code (from different .h/.cpp files, so 
don't pay attention to errors due to declaration order. )
@Vlad: TU means Technical university, though, as you can see, I'm not studying computer science.

FIRST TRY:

```
class quiz{
public:
quiz(int& argc, char** argv,const char* file);
void play(int N=3)const;
protected:
  quiz_content qc;
  QApplication* pa;
  MainWindow* pw;
};

quiz::quiz(int& argc, char** argv, const char* file):qc(file){
// starting Application with Welcome Window
pa=new QApplication(argc, argv);
pw=new MainWindow();
pw->show();
pa->exec();}


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
protected:
QLabel* qlf, *qls;
QVector<QCheckBox*> qla;
QButtonGroup* qba;};

MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent),qla(3)
{ // Welcome Wondow with checkboxes for desired level of game...
// everything works fine, but...
// to start quiz with desired level: can method from quiz be a slot for  MainWindow?
// and if so, how will it be mentioned properly?
connect(qba,SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(quiz::play(int)));
...}`
```

NEXT TRY the other way round with QApplication in main:

```
class quiz{
public:
quiz(const char* file);
// how can method play of element q influence the other elements of the 
// MainWindow Object for displaying text, etc.?
void play(int N=3)const;
protected:
quiz_content qc;};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
protected:
QLabel* qlf, *qls;
QVector<QCheckBox*> qla;
QButtonGroup* qba;
quiz q;};
```

Comment: Susi what does mean TU in your profile here? Is it an University?

Comment: Could you please post sample code. I don't really get what you try to tell me there.

Comment: The main difference is while a console application usually has some linear or state machine based flow, a GUI must be implemented event oriented. The Qt docs provide "Getting Started" guides how to implement GUI applications; if you have specific problems you should provide a [MCVE] to get appropriate help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean either. Maybe a small diagram, some sample code of what you tried ? Using "standard code" with Qt code is totally possible and it is not an issue but as @Murphy said, the here architectural differences between a console app and a gui app. It really depends how modular you game is.

Comment: I'd like to request this question to be reopened. It is about application architecture instead of programming details, and the blurry scope and poor wording is probably due to the OPs inexperience and lack of terminology, but I consider it a valid and good question (the more compared with other questions that pop up on SO these days...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your approach and your question completely, but I'll give it a try. Unfortunately your code samples are far from complete, but I'll focus on the bigger image. I just wonder if what you've build so far works at all, as I'm missing `main()` and a couple of other things.

As mentioned a GUI is event oriented (and events are often, but not always, triggered by the user), and usually the UI classes take a central place and function which control the user interaction: what the user sees and what she can do. If I understand your architecture correctly the class `quiz` is what I would call the *business logic*, which contains the current state of the proceeding quiz and implements how actions manipulate the stored data, affecting what information and possibilities the UI provides at a given time. Simple applications implement the business logic in the UI class(es), but it is indeed good practice to move the logic into a separate class/module, which is called from the UI classes.

Enter Qt: In `main()` you usually instantiate a `QApplication` and the main window, `QApplication::exec()` yields control to the event loop of Qt, which enables the window(s) to listen to user interaction and process the events. E. g. pressing a button would call a connected slot (which is nothing else but a method that reacts accordingly to the event). So you have a main window object handling the user interaction, and some business logic to do calculations and telling the UI what to show next.

And now back to your specific question, as far as I understood it: Your second try seems closer to the architecture outlined above and what I would apply at a first try: Instantiating a main window object which holds an instance of the business logic in a member variable, calling its methods to trigger the progress of the quiz and use the return values to control what the UI is providing to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Murphy, you understood perfectly right :-)

I will pursue the suggestion you made in the last section. However, this means, that `quiz` has to be more modular. Instead of one big method `quiz::play`, that rules the whole game, `quiz` has to provide methods like `QString quiz::nextQuestion()`,`unsigned int quiz::updateScore()`, etc.

So my conclusions are:

- If I want to develop code that shall use GUI features later on,
  already when implementing it as console application I have to think
  about modules appropriate for exchanging information with the GUI
  object(s).
- The logic is part of the GUI object, not vice versa.

I'm impressed by the numerous immediate and helpful reactions to my first question ever posted in a forum. Thank you!

Comment: You got that right, Susi. Good luck with your project! And please mark my answer as accepted if you think it is correct.